# Pop navigation controller on another navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

To get a Navigation Controller on a modal segue I figured I'd try to create the hierarchy as you can see in the screenshot.

What is the right way in this outlet to exit the modal (Login Info View Controller)?

I tried some different stuff:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    //none of these works.. (only tried one at a time..)
    [self.navigationController removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point you want to dismiss the modal viewController, use this line within the class:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

So, in your case, it becomes:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```